# JavaScript / Matter.js : Object with multiple constraints just lifts up

Tags: javascript, physics-engine, matter.js

I tried to build a little "car" to get familiar with the Matter.js API. I almost did it, when something weird happened. I have a main body, connected with two constraints each, to both of the wheels. But once the car reaches the ground, the rear axis lifts off the ground slowly.
Is this a bug, and how can I fix this issue?
code:

```
start()
function start() {
    var Engine = Matter.Engine,
        World = Matter.World,
        Bodies = Matter.Bodies;
        Constraint = Matter.Constraint;
        Render = Matter.Render;

    var engine = Engine.create(document.body);
    var body = Bodies.rectangle(200, 20, 200, 40);
    body.density = 15;
    var wheelA = Bodies.circle(50,100,40);
    var wheelB = Bodies.circle(350,100,40);
    wheelA.density = 10;
    wheelB.density = 10;
    var axisAA = Constraint.create({bodyB:wheelA,bodyA:body,pointA:{x:-90,y:-15},pointB:{x:0,y:0},stiffness:0.8}, { isStatic: true });
    var axisAB = Constraint.create({bodyB:wheelA,bodyA:body,pointA:{x:-10,y:15},pointB:{x:0,y:0},stiffness:0.2});
    var axisBA = Constraint.create({bodyB:wheelB,bodyA:body,pointA:{x:90,y:-15},pointB:{x:0,y:0},stiffness:0.8});
    var axisBB = Constraint.create({bodyB:wheelB,bodyA:body,pointA:{x:10,y:15},pointB:{x:0,y:0},stiffness:0.2});
    var ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, { isStatic: true });

    World.add(engine.world, [body, wheelA, wheelB, axisAA, axisAB, axisBA, axisBB, ground]);

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 39) {
        Matter.Body.setAngularVelocity(wheelA,0.1);
        Matter.Body.setAngularVelocity(wheelB,0.1);
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 37) {
        Matter.Body.setAngularVelocity(wheelA,-0.1);
        Matter.Body.setAngularVelocity(wheelB,-0.1);
    }
    });
    Engine.run(engine);
}
```

Thank you for hopefully coming answers.

Answer (score 0):

There's a known issue that certain constraint setups can't resolve well and this looks to be the case, see here: https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/93

Here's an example of a simple car that sort of works: http://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#car

But note that since revolute constraints are not yet implemented, they will still be a bit unstable unless you make the axle constraints pretty loose.